# How do I draw lines that end with an ellipsis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What's the easiest way to draw lines in Tikz with one or both ends continuing as ... to signify that they continue to infinity? Can I define a arrowhead with an ellipsis?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest would be, in fact, to create a custom arrow tip.

### Version 3.0.0, new `arrows.meta`

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  .../.tip={[sep=0pt 1]
    Round Cap[]. Circle[length=0pt 1] Circle[length=0pt 1] Circle[length=0pt 1, sep=0pt]},
  sss/.tip={[sep=0pt 1]
    Butt Cap[] . Square[length=0pt 1] Square[length=0pt 1] Square[length=0pt 1, sep=0pt]}}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={gridded,line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\tikz \path[...-...] (0,0) edge (1,1);
\tikz \path[sss-sss] (0,0) edge (1,1);
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]  [image]

### Version 2.10, old arrows

I created two, the `...` and the `sss` (`s` for **s**quared) that include three little dots (or squared). Take a look at the examples and the `line cap` setting how the effect the spacing. The dots may be too thin for the usual line width of `.4pt` so you might change the radius or the side length or the spacing between the dots or …

Other solutions could involve a combination of the `*` and the `space` arrow tip as well as using a special `dash pattern`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{...}{...}{%
  \pgfutil@tempdima\pgflinewidth
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+6.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+6.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
}{
  \pgfutil@tempdima\pgflinewidth
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{+2\pgfutil@tempdima}{+0pt}}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{+4\pgfutil@tempdima}{+0pt}}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{+6\pgfutil@tempdima}{+0pt}}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{sss}{sss}{%
  \pgfutil@tempdima\pgflinewidth
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+6\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+6\pgfutil@tempdima}%
}{
  \pgfutil@tempdima\pgflinewidth
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{+2\pgfutil@tempdima}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{+4\pgfutil@tempdima}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{+6\pgfutil@tempdima}{+.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={gridded,line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\tikz \path[...-...,line cap=round] (0,0) edge (1,1);
\tikz \path[...-..., line cap=rect] (0,0) edge (1,1);
\tikz \path[sss-sss] (0,0) edge (1,1);
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image] [image] [image]